# Why does the following program works fine? I am returning a reference to local variable from a function

Tags: c++, function, reference

I am baffled how come the following program works fine. I am returning a reference to local variable from a function and a reference is assigned a value more than once. I would expect compiler to throw an error for reference assignment.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int& getNum()
{
    int myNum = 89;
    return myNum;
}

int& getAnotherNum()
{
    int myNum = 1000;
    return myNum;
}

int main()
{
    int& Value1 = getAnotherNum();   
    cout << "Value1 value is: " << Value1 << endl;

    Value1 = getNum();     
    cout << "Value1 value is: " << Value1 << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is just *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: It works cause you're lucky.

Comment: It is working, but probably not correctly. It is interpreting that address as an `int`, but anything may be there after you leave the function and `myNum` falls out of scope.

Comment: @IvanGrynko **un** lucky! The best you can hope for with UB is a very noisy crash letting you know you've done something badly wrong. If it appears to work, it'll bite you in the bum later.

Comment: It is possible for undefined behavior to produce the *right* behavior

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Comment: Compile with all warnings and the compiler should **warn** you that you return the address of a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is undefined behavior. As per §1.3.24, *undefined behavior* is described as:

> behavior for which this International Standard imposes no requirements

Contrary to popular belief this doesn't mean it will always produce an error. The standard just imposes no requirements whatsoever.

---

> Why did it allow "Value1 = getNum(); ". Value1 is a reference, already assigned to something.

Because in:

```
Value1 = getNum();
```

you are not reassigning a reference. You are calling `operator=` on an `int` which copied the value of the returned value of `getNum` to `Value1`.

Comment: Why did it allow "Value1 = getNum(); ". Value1 is a reference, already assigned to something.